# Cannot add an image into a column in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok , So I'm building this website, everything fine untill now, but I cannot add a image in a column.

Here is my code`

```
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                <h3><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Bootstrap 3 Built</h3>
                <p>The 'Modern Business' website template by <a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Start Bootstrap</a> is built with <a href="http://getbootstrap.com">Bootstrap 3</a>. Make sure you're up to date with latest Bootstrap documentation!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                <h3>de ce noi?</h3>
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nulla massa, venenatis id auctor quis, hendrerit et ipsum. In lacinia nec diam quis imperdiet. Vestibulum malesuada sodales libero, eu luctus tellus rutrum non. Fusce mi nibh, porttitor vel sollicitudin quis, semper et quam. In condimentum tempus ligula, sed pellentesque sem condimentum nec. Aliquam turpis magna, blandit et dignissim non, rutrum non est. Vestibulum iaculis mauris vel magna euismod sollicitudin. Aenean sit amet massa ac lacus tincidunt sodales. Morbi at lacinia arcu. Nunc ut elementum massa.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                <h3>serviciile noastre</h3>
                <img src="http://imgur.com/wI66dTz" alt="bifa">

                <p>Parcare Gratuita</p>
                <p>Parcare Gratuita</p>
            </div>
             <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                <h3><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Bootstrap 3 Built</h3>
                <p>The 'Modern Business' website template by <a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Start Bootstrap</a> is built with <a href="http://getbootstrap.com">Bootstrap 3</a>. Make sure you're up to date with latest Bootstrap documentation!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->`
```

In the third Column there is absolutely no way to add an image, I have tried both uploading the image to the web on imgur and I also have it in my source folder, tried linking directly to it.When I tried from the source folder netbeans gave an error saying the resource could not be loaded(as if it wasn't there) ,but the png is just fine.

Anyone have an ideea how I can solve this?

Comment: `http://imgur.com/wI66dTz` isn't an image. `http://i.imgur.com/wI66dTz.png` is.

Comment: I'm an idiot.Thank you.It works.Still don't understand why it doesen't work when I have it saved in my source folder.

Comment: maybe you are referring to the wrong folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it the wrong way you need to use the direct link to your Image file ending in an  file type extension like `.jpg`, `.png`, `.bmp` etc...

If you have uploaded an image to some file sharing website you will need the **Download url** to that image file which you can obtain by downloading the file then copying the link address by right clicking on the file in browser downloads window.

There are other way but this was simpler to explain.

More about inserting Images in HTML: [Basic HTML: Adding Images](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/html/article.php/3478181)